# Image Segmentation Class weight using tensorflow keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow, class-imbalance, image-segmentation

I remember definitely being able to pass a list to `class_weight` with keras (binary image segmentation specifically). For example:

`class_weight = [1, 10]` (1:10 class weighting)

But now it's saying it has to take a dictionary instead of a list.

```
weights = {0: 1, 1: 10}
```

Well, when I do that I get the error:

```
`class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.
```

Has something changed? I didn't think I'd have so many issues here.

Comment: There is a good discussion here - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3653

Comment: I'm looking for similar answers as I type this, and I just found a good answer here:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013674/keras-pixelwise-class-imbalance-in-binary-image-segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013674/keras-pixelwise-class-imbalance-in-binary-image-segmentation)